# Error en instalación de Obspy en python 3.8.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Soy un iniciado en el mundo de python. Al instalar el paquete obspy da un error durante la instalación y el paquete no finaliza la instalación. Pego lo que sale...

```
Installing collected packages: future, scipy, six, python-dateutil, pyparsing, kiwisolver, cycler, matplotlib, lxml, sqlalchemy, decorator, urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, obspy.    
Running setup.py install for future ... done
Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy ... done    
Running setup.py install for obspy ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Aquí pego una parte del extracto del error. Pongo una parte porque son más de 600 líneas creo.

```
command: 'c:\users\peopl\desktop\bo\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\peopl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51l3yx90\\obspy\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\peopl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51l3yx90\\obspy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\peopl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0by4mla7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\peopl\desktop\bo\env\include\site\python3.8\obspy'

cwd: C:\Users\peopl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-51l3yx90\obspy\

Complete output (651 lines):

C:\Users\peopl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-51l3yx90\obspy\setup.py:555: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
      'system-libs': setuptools.Feature(

C:\Users\peopl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-51l3yx90\obspy\setup.py:546: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
      setuptools.Feature.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

c:\users\peopl\desktop\bo\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\numpy_distribution.py:16: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.

Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)

running install

running build

running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src
    build_src
```

Tras esto muchas líneas de este estilo:

```
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy
copying obspy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy\clients
copying obspy\clients\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy\clients
copying obspy\clients\httpproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy\clients
copying obspy\clients\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\obspy\clients
```

Y al final de todo estas líneas con un error al final.

```
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
building 'libgse2_Windows_32bit_py38' extension
compiling C sources
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

También he instalado una versión superior a esa desde la página que indica pero sigue dando el

Y tras esto un chorro de líneas en rojo. En el entorno donde lo estoy instalando no aparece la carpeta obspy, sí otras como matplotlib, scipy, ...

¿Sabéis cuál es el problema?

Comment: Hola! Por favor, añade algo de ese chorro de líneas en rojo porque no sabemos por qué se quejó la instalación :)

Comment: Gracias por tu interés. Lo pego en una nueva respuesta. Pensaba que con lo que indicaba ya podía orientar en algo. Perdón por el desconocimiento...

Comment: Hola. He editado la pregunta aportando más información sobre el error ya que no entendí bien al principio como funcionaba el sitio web. Pido disculpas.

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, por favor márcala como aceptada. Si tú mismo encontraste la respuesta, escribe la respuesta y en un par de días podrás aceptarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que se puede ver que el error es:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```

Para solucionarlo puedes instalar puedes instalar el vc14 o superior, te dejo el enlace del 16.

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al final lo solucioné durante estas vacaciones de Navidad instalando el paquete de herramientas desde este enlace:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Pero vamos, que es lo que tu me comentas pero con otra versión. Tomo tu respuesta como válida. Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto! Saludos.